# How to fix "Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Unable to find module with ID: aurelia-bootstrap-datetimepicker" issue?

Tags: datatable, aurelia, datetimepicker

I am quite stuck in including **Aurelia-Bootstrap-Datetimepicker** and **aurelia-datatable** in my project. I have followed these two tutorials word by word:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/aurelia-bootstrap-datetimepicker

https://www.npmjs.com/package/aurelia-datatable

Unluckily in both of them I am getting same issue:

```
Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Unable to find module with ID: aurelia-bootstrap-datetimepicker

Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Unable to find module with ID: aurelia-datatable
```

I have observed that this error comes by including plugin in main.ts, like:

```
export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
  aurelia.use
    .standardConfiguration()
    .plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-validation'))
    .feature(PLATFORM.moduleName('resources/index'))
    .plugin('aurelia-bootstrap-datetimepicker');

  aurelia.use.developmentLogging(environment.debug ? 'debug' : 'warn');

  if (environment.testing) {
    aurelia.use.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-testing'));
  }

  aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot(PLATFORM.moduleName('app')));
}
```

Is there any developer who have successfully configured both of these in his/her project? I could create a gist or something to share more stuff..

Or suggest me some other tutorial to follow for meeting both purposes.. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Aurelia with Webpack,try to init the plugin with

```
.plugin(PLATFORM.moduleName('aurelia-bootstrap-datetimepicker'));
```